# Laravel 5.1 Authentication - Create user data in another table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

My authentication and everything is working. I can log in/log out and etc. I have two tables, one is called users which is the default for the authentication and the second one is called players which will be used for the player data.  I made a Player model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'players';

        /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'wood'];
}
```

and edited the AuthController class to this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|min:4|max:32|unique:players',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return Player::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'wood' => 0,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I register a new user the user data gets created in the users table but nothing happens with my players table. It's just empty.

Comment: I'm marking this as needs editing; however, more specifically: you should demonstrate what you've done to diagnose the problem ... something a little more informative than `... but nothing happens with my players table.  It's just empty." would make it easier for the SO community to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you exit from method after inserting data to User table.
Wrong code here:

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
```

Need:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
         User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return Player::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'wood' => 0,
        ]);
    }
```